# Point my domain to subdomain on different host

Tags: dns, subdomain, pythonanywhere

I bought a domain through domain.com and i have a website that is hosted on pythonanywherw, And they provided me a URL subdomain for my site eg. site.pythonanywhere.com
Now how to point my new domain so when anyone visits my domain they get my website on pythonanywherw displayed?
(It's one page website or landing page)
I made a CNAME with www and site pythonanywherw.com as the target but when i visit my domain i done see my website and see error message that site is not found that's because in CNAME it added www before the subdomain eg. [www.site.pythonanywherw.com](http://www.site.pythonanywherw.com)
So it's not correct URL so it showed me not found message.

Answer (score 1):

- [you could use a proxy that forwards the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974100/how-to-use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-cross-domains)
- you could host your application with render.com or koyeb.com , they allow custom domains including ssl , pythonanywhere will charge you $$$

regards

Answer (score 0):

To host web app on custom domain on PythonAnywhere, you need a paid account.

Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/CustomDomains